# How to get specific values in from a pandas data frame using python?

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, analytics

I'm trying to run the script below:

```
g20s = ['Argentina, Australia, Brazil, Canada, China, France, Germany, India, Indonesia, Italy, Japan, Mexico, Republic of Korea, Russia, Saudi Arabia, South Africa, Turkey, United Kingdom, United States, European Union']

gdp_g20 = gdp_world.loc(gdp_world['Country Name'].isin(g20s))
```

But I'm gettin the error below:

TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Any idea of how get these values from the dataframe without having this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you should change your list to
`g20s = ['Argentina', 'Australia', 'Brazil', ........]`
Make each country a separate string in the list `g20s`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the "(" and ")"

Try this:
gdp_g20 = gdp_world[gdp_world['Country Name'].isin(g20s)]